# How to dynamically reconfigure without running the robot?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to dynamically reconfigure a parameter as mentioned in this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/325899/rosbags-record-parameter-server-data/?answer=325900#post-id-325900), I do not want to run the robot for it, instead I want some way to get data from the robot and then work on the dynamic reconfiguration part. I need something similar to `rosbags` but not `rosbags` since they use topics to record data as mentioned in the [answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/325899/rosbags-record-parameter-server-data/?answer=325900#post-id-325900)

EDIT1: adding more information

I am working with a Velodyne VLP-16 LIDAR, since its a very costly sensor I have to work with bag files, actually its a 16-channel LIDAR and I want to reconfigure its disk value from the default `8` to `2`, Here is the `rosbag info`:

```
path:        third_run.bag
  version:     2.0
  duration:    1:02s (62s)
  start:       Dec 05 2018 12:34:13.22 (1543993453.22)
  end:         Dec 05 2018 12:35:15.56 (1543993515.56)
  size:        469.3 MB
  messages:    2294
  compression: none [571/571 chunks]
  types:       bond/Status                           
               diagnostic_msgs/DiagnosticArray      
               dynamic_reconfigure/Config           
               dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription
               sensor_msgs/LaserScan                
               sensor_msgs/PointCloud2              
               velodyne_msgs/VelodyneScan           
  topics:      /diagnostics                                                  62 msgs    : diagnostic_msgs/DiagnosticArray      
               /scan                                                        617 msgs    : sensor_msgs/LaserScan                
               /velodyne_nodelet_manager/bond                               372 msgs    : bond/Status                          
               /velodyne_nodelet_manager_cloud/parameter_descriptions         1 msg     : dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription
               /velodyne_nodelet_manager_cloud/parameter_updates              1 msg     : dynamic_reconfigure/Config           
               /velodyne_nodelet_manager_driver/parameter_descriptions        1 msg     : dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription
               /velodyne_nodelet_manager_driver/parameter_updates             1 msg     : dynamic_reconfigure/Config           
               /velodyne_nodelet_manager_laserscan/parameter_descriptions     1 msg     : dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription
               /velodyne_nodelet_manager_laserscan/parameter_updates          1 msg     : dynamic_reconfigure/Config           
               /velodyne_packets                                            618 msgs    : velodyne_msgs/VelodyneScan           
               /velodyne_points                                             619 msgs    : sensor_msgs/PointCloud2
```

As you can see, it has dynamically reconfigurable parameters, which I want to configure through code so I can get the data I want, but as I mentioned above, it is not possible with bag files. So, I am looking for something similar to bag files where I have access to param server

EDIT2: Replaced image with text

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325902/how-to-dynamically-reconfigure-without-running-the-robot?/) by [khansaadbinhasan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33367/khansaadbinhasan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2019-06-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-06-16**:
Can you be specific about which node or nodes you're trying to configure and the end goal that you're trying to achieve by changing the node's parameters?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-06-16**:
Please don't use an image to post text. See the [support page](https://wiki.ros.org/Support#Do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It *looks* like you want to take the velodyne_laserscan node and choose a different ring than the one that was chosen when the log was recorded.

You can do this by running the following commands In separate terminals:

- `roscore`
- `rosrun veldoyne_laserscan velodyne_laserscan_node`
- `rosbag play my_bag.bag --topics /velodyne_points`

Since you're running the velodyne_laserscan_node, you'll be able to reconfigure it and select a different ring.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [khansaadbinhasan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33367/khansaadbinhasan/) on 2019-06-17**:
As I mentioned in Edit1, I do not have access to LIDAR, I only have bag files, so I cannot run the second command. As I discussed with `@PeteBlackerThe3rd` in the comments, this can be done with running a simulation in `Gazebo`. If you know of any other way I can test `dynamic reconfiguration` without a real LIDAR please let me know

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-06-17**:
You do not need access to the robot to run `velodyne_laserscan_node`. It simply converts the `/velodyne_points` topic to the `/scan` topic, and since you have recorded the `/velodyne_points` topic, you can play back that topic and run it without a robot.

**Comment by [khansaadbinhasan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33367/khansaadbinhasan/) on 2019-06-17**:
Thanks for the answer! it works.